# Wordpress 404 works for non existing page but not for non existing images

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

http://localhost/wordpress/not-found-page.php `=>` goes to `404` not found page
http://localhost/wordpress/not-found-image.png `=>` goes to server `404` error page

[server error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVdi4.png)

I have added this code in `.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
```

Below is the current .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the 'fastcgi_intercept_errors' argument from you configuration if exists. It's unnecessary since 'error_page' declares 404 errors, which should be handled by index.php, which will trigger PHP-FPM to handle it, and WordPress to present your theme's 404 page.

If this does not work then:

Add the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ /index.php?error=404 [R]
```

This will redirect a png/jpeg/gif/ico file If it does not exist to /index.php?error=404

Comment: Hi @Pratik thank you for the reply. This one works on localhost but on the server it is not working.

Comment: Hi @Rushanthan Not working does not mean anything, What is the issue you are getting? Is it not opening 404 page? Try setting up custom error page in your server panel if cpanel or plesk or any other.

Comment: Hi @Pratik. **On the server**, the custom **404 error page** is not opening for certain files with certain extension like **.png, jpg,** etc. But on the localhost it is opening the 404 error page without any trouble.

Comment: @Rushanthan Have you removed fastcgi_intercept_errors and tried as per the above?

Comment: Hi @Pratik. I talked with the support team as this is not allowed to change from our end. Anyway thanks for the help. It was useful.

Comment: @Rushanthan :-)